# length (byte-wise) of a string in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, string-length

How do we find out the length (byte-wise) of a string `[declared String type, not NSString]` in Swift 2.2?

I know one way out is to use `_bridgeToObejectiveC().length`

Is there any other way out?

Comment: `someString.characters.count` returns the length of the String. I think I didn't get what you're asking really.

Comment: character count and length are two different things. Swift uses unicode. In unicode, different characters take different number of bytes for storage. I wish to know 'how many bytes a string' is taking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think type casting is another easier way to use the methods, properties of NSString class.

```
print((str as NSString).length)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let str: String = "Hello, World"
print(str.characters.count) // 12

let str1: String = "Hello, World"
print(str1.endIndex) // 12

let str2 = "Hello, World"
NSString(string: str2).length  //12
```

Refer [String length in Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575140/string-length-in-swift-1-2-and-swift-2-0) and [Get the length of a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037711/get-the-length-of-a-string)

Comment: In case you need to do special unicode shenanigans also look into `str.utf8.count` and `str.utf16.count`

Comment: that is one answer

Answer (score 3):

```
    let str: String = "Hello, World"
    print(str.characters.count) // 12
    let byteLength = str.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("byte lenght: \(byteLength)")//12

    let str2: String = "你好"
    print(str2.characters.count) // 2
    let byteLength2 = str.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("byte lenght: \(byteLength2)")//12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

> Swift

```
    let test : String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    let bytes : NSInteger =   test.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSLog("%i bytes", bytes);
```

> Objective C

refer this link:

[What is the length in bytes of a NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245188/what-is-the-length-in-bytes-of-a-nsstring)

Comment: This is pretty much what KawaiKx said they're *not* interested in: The `NSString` way...

Comment: you are also use String. This isn't imported string to find bytes imported.

Comment: Okay, now you edited your answer. I agree that it doesn't really matter, I was just pointing it out. Also, I have no clue what your comment says, sorry.